# I am encountering a permission error in Laravel. Any suggestions?

Tags: laravel-5

This is the error:

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/{project_name}/public/temp/ttfontdata/dejavuserifcondensed.mtx.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied.
```